# How do I add minutes step to Bootstrap DateTimePicker?

Tags: datetime, datetimepicker, picker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I tried with this and other methods, but it's still not working.

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'HH:mm',
        disabledTimeIntervals: [[moment({ h: 0 }), moment({ h: 6 })], [moment({ h: 17, m: 30 }), moment({ h: 24 })]],
        enabledHours: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
        minuteStepping: 15
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to use [`stepping`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#stepping) option to achieve what you need:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'HH:mm',
        disabledTimeIntervals: [[moment({ h: 0 }), moment({ h: 6 })], [moment({ h: 17, m: 30 }), moment({ h: 24 })]],
        enabledHours: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
        stepping: 15
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```